# Eigenvalues in the semiclassical limit

Tags: schrodinger-operators, eigenvector

Consider the Schrödinger operator $H_\hbar = -\hbar^2\Delta + V$ on $M=\mathbb{R}^n$, where $V$ is a potential that behaves well in a certain sense ($C^\infty$, bounded from below, going to infinity for large $|x|$, ...).

In the case $V = x^2$, $n=1$, the eigenfunctions are $\psi_n(x/\sqrt{\hbar})$ where the $\psi_n$ are hermite functions, and the corresponding eigenvalues are $\hbar(2n+1)$.

My question is: Is it a well-known theorem, that in the semiclassical limit $\hbar \rightarrow 0$, the eigenvalues tend to the minimum or minima of $V$ and the corresponding eigenvectors behave asymptotically like delta peaks? Can you give me references?

What about if M is a (possibly compact) riemannian manifold and $\Delta$ the Laplace-Beltrami operator?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The canonical reference is:

Introduction to spectral theory: with applications to Schrödinger operators by Hislop and Sigal.

Your statement about the semiclassical behavior of eigenvalues seems to be proved by Barry Simon in:

http://archive.numdam.org/ARCHIVE/AIHPA/AIHPA_1983__38_3/AIHPA_1983__38_3_295_0/AIHPA_1983__38_3_295_0.pdf

(where he calls it a "folk theorem").

Answer (score 4):

Another reference is Helffer and several Coauthors (Sjöstrand, Nier, Klein, Garyard, ...) using the Witten-Laplace approach.

An introduction is given in the book
[Semiclassical analysis, Witten Laplacians, and statistical mechanics](https://books.google.de/books?id=43vAd5KoEkUC)

Later sharp asymptotics for the low lying spectra in the case where $V$ consists of several minima were obtained. Some lecture note on this topic [Low lying eigenvalues of Witten Laplacians and metastability (after Helffer-Klein-Nier and Helffer-Nier)](https://www.math.kth.se/spect/preprints04_05/Helf3.pdf).

If you are only interessted in the Schrödinger Operator, maybe the book [Semi-Classical Analysis for the Schrödinger Operator and Applications](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/BFb0078115?from=SL) is the most interesting for you. There are also lecture notes available [Semiclassical Analysis for Schrödinger Operators, Laplace Integrals and Transfer Operators in large dimension: an introduction.](http://www.math.u-psud.fr/%7Ehelffer/CoursDEA95main.ps)